# Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate, Enterprise Distribution

Tags: ios

I get this error when I want to export my project for Enterprise Distribution. But the funny thing is that I have all my certificates installed on the machine, so nothing should be wrong. Why can't Xcode import them if it knows I have a valid one? This is just stupid! Always these kinds of problems when distributing iOS apps, and always a different problem every time, with the certificates.

Comment: It would be easier to help if we knew your setup - screen shots, ini files, code, manifest whatever.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the some reason for this error.

Your app is already live or review in appstore at that time this error is occured

**Solution**

> you can clear `DrivedData` and make a new build file
>
> Create a new `AdHoc` Provisioning And Download and after select that
>   certificates and make new build file

I hope this help you.